# How to enqueue a custom JavaScript file with Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to insert an HTML file inside a modal. I'm aware I need to enqueue a custom JS file from the functions.php in my Wordpress theme. I'm not entirely sure which type of enqueue code I should use in order to start a script that will get the following script to work:

Wordpress page code:

```
<a class='example7' href="http://google.com">Outside Webpage (Iframe)</a>
```

Custom JavaScript code:
    $(".example7").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:425, innerHeight:344});

Comment: Do you mean you don't know how to enqueue script right ?

Comment: That's right. In my functions.php file it looks like the specific themes JS is written somewhere else as that file is mainly empty

Answer (score 1):

Not everytime you have to enqueue script inside functions.php. Then also you can do this like below:

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

You can add your Custom JavaScript code: `$(".example7").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:425, innerHeight:344});` in header.php file.

Comment: pasting the code in the header PHP file didn't seem to work. :-(

Comment: @Marc Have you write `$(".example7").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:425, innerHeight:344});` inside `<script></script>`? If yes then also not work then see the console any error is displays or not.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain Kausha, but that didn't work... also there were no errors in the console for that page...

Comment: @Marc No problem, Ok, do one thing first check the view source the js file you enqueue that is listed or not? Then check jQuery min is shown or not in view source and last but not list check that the code you wrote in header.php that is displayed in view source or not. And let me know

Comment: Just to clarify this is what I've done... I'm worried I may have been too stupid to understand what you have instructed.

1. inserted JS into header.php as follows:
'
// start output buffer to capture content for use in footer.php

<script>
$(".example7").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:425, innerHeight:344});
</script>
ob_start();

do_action('wp_enqueue_scripts');
'

Comment: [link](http://challenge-the-box.com/pricing) is where the source code should be showing up. But I can't seem to find it on there.

Comment: @Marc Yes, i didn't see that too. Have you check the theme in which you are doing changes that is activated from admin side?

Comment: Here's an update: I managed to find a custom script box in my theme's admin area. I have now put the JS in that and kept the html on the page. Both show up in the source window now, however the hypertext doesn't open a modal... hmmmm